# The voltage becomes zero when the load is connected

Tags: mosfet, h-bridge, load

This is my circuit.

When I connect the load of 10 Ohm, the voltage goes to zero!

The voltage goes to zero even if I put resistor of 10 kOhm.

[image]

Comment: You'll need to do much better fault diagnostics than that! The voltage **where** is zero? How did you measure? What is the voltage at the connection between Q1 and Q2? And Q3 - Q4? Are you getting drive signals to the MOSFETS? etc., etc., etc.

Comment: Also, what is your load? a dc motor I guess?

Comment: Can the power supply deliver 9000 W?

Comment: @Transistor The load voltage becomes zero, I measured with an oscilloscope and voltmeter

Comment: @ChristianidisVasileios yes

Comment: @AnalogKid In fact, the supply voltage is 12 volts, not 300 volts

Comment: Yes, an h bridge is supposed to do that at idle. But does it have a signal across the load when the input  receives a signal ? (with the probe +/- leads measuring across the load)

Answer (score 3):

I assume there's a question hiding in there somewhere. Let's pretend the question is, "Why is the voltage across a 10-ohm load zero?"

Let's start with the basics. Check to see that IN1 and IN2 are actually different. One should be high and one should be low. Are you letting them float? If you're driving them from something like an Arduino, and you've screwed up your code, it's entirely possible that both inputs are being commanded to the same level. In that case, both sides of the load will be driven to the same level, and the current through the load will be zero.

If the input levels are correct, shrug. Who knows? You've provided no information, especially voltages at various points on the circuit. At a guess, it's because your MOSFETs are not getting any gate drive.

Why would that be? Any number of reasons. You might have miswired the IR2110s. You might have connected the FETS backwards. You might have used the wrong component values - for instance, if you used 10k resistors instead of 10 ohm resistors for R1, R2, R5 and R6, that would explain it.

But there's no way to tell without you doing a lot more work. Among other things, the accuracy of your schematic is not exactly without question - if you got the load supply voltage wrong (300 V instead of 12), who knows what other errors you've made?

So. Check to see that ALL of your grounds are actually tied together. Check to see that both your +5 and +12 are present at every point they should be. Check for the value of Vs on both drivers - it should be about +12 on one of them. Check to make sure that +12 is being applied to the correct pins of Q1 and Q3. Check the gate-source voltages of all the MOSFETs.

Comment: A valiant attempt to imagine a Universe by looking at a drop of water :)

Comment: Also worth noting that a bootstrapping driver like the IR2110 needs periodic switching to keep the bootstrap capacitor charged. If he is simply turning on the high side mosfet statically it won't stay on for long.

Comment: @Maple - Thank you. I deliberately refrained from asking if his power supplies were both plugged in and turned on.

Comment: @Unimportant - I don't think that's true. There is an internal pulse generator which I believe takes care of that.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the important comment from @Unimportant, the [IR2110](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IR2110-DataSheet-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355c80333167e) uses a bootstrap configuration to generate the gate drive voltage for the high-side MOSFETs, so you cannot have an output high continuously, the gate voltage will leak off and the UVLO will engage.

[image]

For example, when your low side MOSFET Q2 is 'on', the bootstrap capacitor C1 || C2 charges toward +12 through the UF4007 diode D1. That charge is used to drive the high-side MOSFET Q1.

So you need Q2 to be switched on regularly, even if it is only for a few microseconds, just long enough for the capacitors to be charged.